# Linear movement image to mouse

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, transform

I have a two points - start and destination. (X, Y) I must to create a bullet. I created a simply code:

```
def Entities():
    ##BULLETS
    #bullets array
    for x in gd.bulletList:
        dist = gd.Dist(
                gd.bulletList[x].X,
                gd.bulletList[x].Y, 
                gd.bulletList[x].MX, 
                gd.bulletList[x].MY)
        ## MX - DestX, MY - DestY, X и Y. Speed - speed.
        if (gd.bulletList[x].X < gd.bulletList[x].MX):
            gd.bulletList[x].X = gd.bulletList[x].speed
        if (gd.bulletList[x].X > gd.bulletList[x].MX):
            gd.bulletList[x].X -= gd.bulletList[x].speed
        if (gd.bulletList[x].Y < gd.bulletList[x].MY):
            gd.bulletList[x].Y += gd.bulletList[x].speed
        if (gd.bulletList[x].Y > gd.bulletList[x].MY):
            gd.bulletList[x].Y -= gd.bulletList[x].speed
        win.blit(spd.sprites['bullet'], (gd.bulletList[x].X, gd.bulletList[x].Y))
```

Create like this:

[image: Preview]

Please help me! **How to create a uniform movement!**

Comment: What exactly is the problem with your code?

Comment: See [Shooting a bullet in pygame in the direction of mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59977052/shooting-a-bullet-in-pygame-in-the-direction-of-mouse/59980344#59980344)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the vector form the bullet position to the target, using [`pygame.math.Vector2`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2):

```py
tragetPos = pygame.math.Vector2(bullet.MX, bullet.MY)
bulletPos = pygame.math.Vector2(bullet.X, bullet.Y)
bulletDir = tragetPos - bulletPos
```

Calculate the length of the vector ([`pygame.math.length()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.length)). The length is the current distance from the bullet to the target:

```py
distance = bulletDir.length()
```

Normalize the direction vector ([`pygame.math.normalize()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.normalize)). This means the vector becomes a [Unit vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) with lenght 1:

```py
bulletDir = bulletDir.normalize()
```

The bullet has to move in the direction of the target by the minimum of the speed (`bullet.speed`) and the distance to the target (the bullet should not go beyond the target). Calculate the new position of the bullet:

```py
bulletPos = bulletPos + bulletDir * min(distance, speed)
```

Finally the attributes `X` and `Y` can be set and the bullet can be `blit`. The function may look like this:

```py
def Entities():

    for bullet in gd.bulletList:

        tragetPos = pygame.math.Vector2(bullet.MX, bullet.MY)
        bulletPos = pygame.math.Vector2(bullet.X, bullet.Y)
        bulletDir = tragetPos - bulletPos
        distance  = bulletDir.length()
        if distance > 0:

            bulletDir = bulletDir.normalize()
            bulletPos = bulletPos + bulletDir * min(distance, speed)

            bullet.X, bullet.Y = bulletPos
            win.blit(spd.sprites['bullet'], (int(bullet.X), int(bullet.Y)))
```