# Problem with programming bullets on a pygame project

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I want to make a shooter in pygame, currently the bullet only goes to the right but that's a placeholder, the real problem is that when i try to spawn my bullets inside my player they just spawn in the inital coordinates of the player, instead of the current ones

Sorry if the code is kinda hard to read, I'm not used to pygame

```
import pygame
import math
from pygame.locals import *
from sys import exit

pygame.init()

screen_width = 640
screen_height = 576
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Hollow Shooter')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load('player.png').convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (100, 100))

    def playerInput(self):
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_w]:
            self.rect.y -= 20
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_a]:
            self.rect.x -= 20
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_s]:
            self.rect.y += 20
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_d]:
            self.rect.x += 20

    def update(self):
        self.playerInput()

    def createBullet(self):
        return Bullet(self.rect.x, self.rect.y)

player = Player()
playerGroup = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle()
playerGroup.add(Player())

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, bulletx, bullety):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((10, 10))
        self.image.fill((255, 0, 0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (bulletx, bullety))
        
    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += 5

bulletGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()

while True:
    clock.tick(30)
    screen.fill((0,0,0))

    playerGroup.update()
    bulletGroup.update()
    playerGroup.draw(screen)
    bulletGroup.draw(screen)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            bulletGroup.add(player.createBullet())  
    
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually you create 2 different player objects. You need to add  `player` to the *Group* instead of creating a new object:

<s>`playerGroup.add(Player())`</s>

```py
playerGroup.add(player)
```

See also [Shooting a bullet in pygame in the direction of mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59977052/shooting-a-bullet-in-pygame-in-the-direction-of-mouse/59980344#59980344).